# Activate worksheet after opening multiple password protected workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code for opening multiple password protected workbooks. At the end of the code I am attempting to reactivate the worksheet in the master workbook. However, it does not reactivate. Possibly due to opening process taking longer that the sub to run? Any suggestions?

I have tried turning off events. Also attempted a wait function.

```
Public Sub OpenFiles()

Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim numClients
Dim pw As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim newHour As Variant
Dim newMinute As Variant
Dim newSecond As Variant
Dim waitTime As Variant

Set mainwb = ThisWorkbook

myPath = mainwb.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C1")
myExtension = ".xlsx"
numClients = mainwb.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("I1")

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 4 To numClients

    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & i).Value
    pw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & i).Value
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw

    DoEvents

Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate

End Sub
```

The activated worksheet is the sheet on the last opened workbook.

Comment: Instead of using `Thisworkbook` call the workbook out by name, that way it know which to activate. This is simply using whichever is currently active and going to that tab.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to activate the specific workbook but you need to put the workbook name in.

`````
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim numClients
Dim pw As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim newHour As Variant
Dim newMinute As Variant
Dim newSecond As Variant
Dim waitTime As Variant

Set mainwb = ThisWorkbook

myPath = mainwb.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C1")
myExtension = ".xlsx"
numClients = mainwb.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("I1")

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 4 To numClients

    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A" & i).Value
    pw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B" & i).Value
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile & myExtension, Password:=pw

    DoEvents

Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 Workbooks("YourWorkbookName.xlsx").Activate 'Put your workbook name here. can add worksheet as well

End Sub````
`````

Comment: Thank you for the help but it is still having the same issue.

Comment: I did. I have it as ````Workbooks("Master XXXX.xlsm").Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate````

Comment: I think the cause is what you suspected where there's a lot going on, and the code is still opening sheets or something basically going over the line that activates the right sheet. Just a guess I'd look into something that ensures it's completed before moving to the next step. like `Do
DoEvents
Loop While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone` or something similar